IIS - Stop application pool from restarting when physical memory limit is reached
I've set my app pool private memory limit to 500mb, and virtual to 0
I expected this to make my application simply start using hard disk after it hits 500mb RAM usage
however the application simply restarts when 500mb ram usage is reached, is this the intended behavior?, is there any way to stop the application from restarting and simply use virtual memory to avoid out of memory exceptions?

Is the behavior you observe directly related to reaching memory limits? Or maybe there could be other reasons why the application is restarting? Use monitoring tools to observe your application's memory usage over time. This will help you determine if the memory limit is reached and what happens next.
